# How to safe_dump the dictionary and list into YAML?

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I want the output as the YAML below:

```
 - item: Food_eat
   Food:
     itemId: 42536216
     category: fruit
     moreInfo:
       - "organic"
```

I have used the following code to print in the same order as above but output is coming not as expected.

Code:

```
import yaml

yaml_result = [{'item': 'Food_eat', 'Food': {'foodNo': 42536216,'type': 'fruit','moreInfo': ['organic']}}]

print(yaml.safe_dump(yaml_result))
print(yaml_test)
```

Output:

```
- Food:
    moreInfo:
    - organic
    category: fruit
    itemId: 42536216
  item: Food_eat
```

Not sure how to get the desired output.

Comment: Your desired output and the actual output represent the same thing. Because Python dictionaries do not have a guaranteed key order, there's not a good way for you to get what you want. If it's just a cosmetic desire to have the output look a certain way, then I'd suggest trying to let that go - for all practical uses they are the same. If you really *MUST* have the desired output you could always generate the YAML yourself (fine for simple data structures, difficult to get right for complex data structures).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ruamel.yaml (disclaimer: I am the author of that package) does have
this feature built-in, as it is necessary to support its capability to
round-trip (load, modify, dump) YAML data without introducing spurious
changes. Apart from that it defaults to YAML 1.2, whereas PyYAML only
supports YAML 1.1 (outdated more than 10 years ago).

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

data = [{'item': 'Food_eat', 'Food': {'foodNo': 42536216,'type': 'fruit','moreInfo': ['organic']}}]

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
  - item: Food_eat
    Food:
      foodNo: 42536216
      type: fruit
      moreInfo:
        - organic
```

This relies on a modern Python's ability to keep the insertion ordering of a dict. For
older versions, like Python 2.7, you'll have to explicitly make an
object `CommentedMap` (as imported from `ruamel.yaml.comments` and
either give it a list of tuples (in the right order), or assign the
key value pairs in the order you want them to be dumped.

As you can see within the indentation of the sequence the dash has an offset, this is something you
cannot achieve using PyYAML without rewriting its emitter.

---

Within PyYAML you don't want to do `print(yaml.safe_dump(data))` as
that is inefficient both wrt. memory and time, always use `yaml.safe_dump(data, sys.stdout)` instead.

Comment: Is there any functionality available in ruamel.yaml to search for string in yaml file.

Comment: The YAML file is just a text file, so you can use the normal search functionality in Python ( using `in`, or `re`), that can also easily give  line, column data. If you are looking for a specific key, value or item (or subset thereof), this can be easily implemented (but is not standard) even if you have tags in your YAML, but you need to decide on some form for the path for the result.  if you want line, column information from that, that is much more difficult. Please ost a question with what you exactly expect.