# How to remove 2 spaces from the output of ruamel.yaml dump?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, ruamel.yaml

With the help of *yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)* the output is correct but there is extra space coming in each line and I know it is due to above indent function. Is there any way to remove the 2 extra spaces from each line(I don't wont to use strip()).

Code:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

data = [{'item': 'Food_eat', 'Food': {'foodNo': 42536216,'type': 'fruit','moreInfo': ['organic']}}]

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

Output of above code:

```
  - item: Food_eat
    Food:
      foodNo: 42536216
      type: fruit
      moreInfo:
        - organic
```

Required output:

```
- item: Food_eat
  Food:
    foodNo: 42536216
    type: fruit
    moreInfo:
      - organic
```

P.S: I have taken help from this stackoverflow question by me:  [How to safe_dump the dictionary and list into YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58734441/how-to-safe-dump-the-dictionary-and-list-into-yaml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not so much the indent, as well as the offset of the sequence
item indicator. This offset is taken within the space before the item
and if the root node is a list, this gives correct YAML, but it looks
sub-optimal.

I have been looking at fixing this, but have not come up with a good solution. Until I
do you'll have to post-process your output, which can be easily done:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

data = [{'item': 'Food_eat', 'Food': {'foodNo': 42536216,'type': 'fruit','moreInfo': ['organic']}}]

def strip_leading_double_space(stream):
    if stream.startswith("  "):
        stream = stream[2:]
    return stream.replace("\n  ", "\n")
    # you could also do that on a line by line basis
    # return "".join([s[2:] if s.startswith("  ") else s for s in stream.splitlines(True)])


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
print('# < to show alignment')
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout, transform=strip_leading_double_space)
```

which gives:

```
# < to show alignment
- item: Food_eat
  Food:
    foodNo: 42536216
    type: fruit
    moreInfo:
      - organic
```

Of course it would be more efficient if the extra start-of-line spaces
would not be generated in the first place.

Comment: Be careful, the fix should only be applied if the root element is a list. If it's not a list, it should not be applied.

Comment: That is not true in general, if your root level is a mapping instead of a sequence, and the indent is more than the default, this will work as well. If you are worried about misapplying this, you better insert `if not stream.startswith('  - '): return stream, as  first statement in `strip_leading_double_space()`.

Comment: Is there a configuration of ruamel.yaml for which a "mapping at the root level with extra indent" would not be pushed backwards (I mean extra indent would be removed) during the roundtrip?

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to. A key in a root level mapping is never indented. An element in a root level sequence is always indented (but the sequence element indicator (`-`) preceding it isn't unless you use `indent(...., offset=X)`, when `X>0`

Comment: I misunderstood your comment. My point is that if the root level is not CommentedSeq you should not have to use the `strip_leading_double_space` as you can play with the `yaml.indent` params to get to what you want. But maybe I'm missing something :)

Comment: `yaml.indent` will only get you consistent indentation on mappings. If you want the root level mapping to indent 2 and the rest for you have to use `indent(4)` + `strip_leading_spaces` with the extra `if not stream......` test