# How to get ruamel yaml to indent nested sequences with 2 spaces

Tags: ruamel.yaml

We are using ruamel.yaml (0.18.6), and want to indent sequences with two leading spaces.  we noticed that it uses a 2-space indent on the first sequence, but switches to a 4-space indent on the second and subsequent levels. As shown below:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Conditions:
  HA: !Equals
    - !FindInMap
        - Environments
        - !Ref 'Environment'
        - HighAvailability
    - 'true'
```

How can we configure ruamel.yaml to consistently indent nested sequences with 2 spaces?

We followed the recommended indent setting of (mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2) as documented [here](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/detail/#indentation-of-block-sequences).

The default format will indent the first level with 0 spaces, and subsequent sequences with 2 spaces as so:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Conditions:
  HA: !Equals
  - !FindInMap
    - Environments
    - !Ref 'Environment'
    - HighAvailability
  - 'true'
```

Answer (score 0):

Both outputs that you show are consistently indented.
The first one 4 positions with an offset of 2 for the dash for each of the sequences and the second one with 2 position and an offset of 0:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Conditions:
  HA: !Equals
    - !FindInMap
        - Environments
        - !Ref 'Environment'
        - HighAvailability
    - 'true'
#       ^ two position offset of dash inner sequence
#     ^ beginning of 4 positions 
#   ^ two positions offset for dash outer sequence
# ^ beginning of 4 positions outer sequence
```

For the second example there is no offset for the indent, that the inner sequence is further indented is a necessity to make it a nested sequence for the first element of the outer sequence:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Conditions:
  HA: !Equals
  - !FindInMap
    - Environments
    - !Ref 'Environment'
    - HighAvailability
  - 'true'
#   ^ zero position offset of dash inner sequence
#   ^ beginning of 4 positions 
# ^ zero positions offset for dash outer sequence
# ^ beginning of 4 positions outer sequence
```

The following would be inconsistent, because the outer sequence would have 4 positions with an offset of 2 and the inner 2 positions with an offset of 0

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Conditions:
  HA: !Equals
    - !FindInMap
      - Environments
      - !Ref 'Environment'
      - HighAvailability
    - 'true'
#     ^ zero position offset of dash inner sequence
#     ^ beginning of 2 positions 
#   ^ two positions offset for dash outer sequence
# ^ beginning of 4 positions outer sequence
```

And `ruamel.yaml` cannot be used to generate such inconsistent formatting.

Comment: Thank you for the time and for your answer Anthon.   The first example is produced by dump after yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2). The second example is the output that dump produces with the default settings.

Indeed, both these are reported by yamllint as inconsistently indented. 

The desired format which you say is inconsistent, passes yamllint without errors. It is also the format that IntelliJ uses when reformatting the yaml.

Is there a way for me to get that format?

Comment: In the above s/Indeed/Unfortunately/

Comment: Yes the indent setting of the first one was clear (at least to me ;-) ). I am not very impressed with yamllint, so I am not surprised why they call something consistent for which ruamel.yaml would need a special option to differentiate between inner and outer sequences. There is no way to get what you want using ruamel.yaml except if you want to do some postprocessing of the output (which is not that difficult on the example, but I don't now how representative that is).

Comment: And the only plans I have for indentation, apart from the current differentiation between sequence and mapping indent is to allow root level sequences to be not indented even if you set `(sequence=4, offset=2)`, as that currently put 2 spaces even before the root level elements (which is consistent, but surprising to many). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58773229/1307905